# CSS: child element with width of 100% only 50% wide

Tags: css, flexbox

At [this page](https://staging.orsgroup.com.au/eapportal/), a header photo is not displaying full width.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 990px;
}
#content-wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.image-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content-wrap" class="fluid clearfix" data-content="content">
    <!-- /#start content-wrap -->
    <div class="image-header">
      <img src="https://staging.orsgroup.com.au/eapportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/07/ORS-Internals-960x211-EmployServOccu21.jpg" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="content" class="sixteen columns">
        <section class="post-9 page type-page status-publish hentry">

          <h1>Home Page</h1>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis tortor vel diam volutpat luctus. Proin placerat nisl nulla, in mattis ex consectetur quis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae enim
            vel nibh hendrerit dignissim a et ante. Mauris eget tempus nunc. Donec dignissim elit sed ullamcorper semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas facilisis, risus eu varius lacinia, diam tortor volutpat ipsum,
            eu luctus neque massa quis leo. Phasellus blandit pellentesque justo non ornare. Cras et elit sit amet quam consequat viverra vel a diam. Pellentesque rutrum, dolor sit amet condimentum dapibus, lorem est dapibus orci, a congue ante ante ac
            lectus. Donec maximus pretium venenatis. Cras ex leo, pellentesque in libero sit amet, auctor congue sapien. Aliquam nec mi commodo ipsum sagittis tincidunt. Vestibulum sollicitudin laoreet eros vel finibus. Integer accumsan consectetur neque
            eget sodales.</p>
        </section>
        <!-- #post-## -->
        <!-- You can start editing here. -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#content-wrap -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, `.image-header` is only displaying around 50% of the width of `#content-wrap`.

I added `width: 100%;` to `#content-wrap` but the issue remains.

I do want to keep the flex model.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I've amended your question to include a full reproducible example in the question itself. For future reference links to external sites are not enough as if the issue gets fixed (or the page disappears) the question will lose all meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why this is happening

This is because you are using the flexbox model, which is attempting to spread the elements on the same line. There are a couple of ways you can avoid this behaviour:

## Allow the content to wrap

By default `flex-wrap` is set to `nowrap` by setting this to `wrap` the text content will be forced onto the next line when it runs out of space.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 990px;
}
#content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.image-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content-wrap" class="fluid clearfix" data-content="content">
    <!-- /#start content-wrap -->
    <div class="image-header">
      <img src="https://staging.orsgroup.com.au/eapportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/07/ORS-Internals-960x211-EmployServOccu21.jpg" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="content" class="sixteen columns">
        <section class="post-9 page type-page status-publish hentry">

          <h1>Home Page</h1>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis tortor vel diam volutpat luctus. Proin placerat nisl nulla, in mattis ex consectetur quis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae enim
            vel nibh hendrerit dignissim a et ante. Mauris eget tempus nunc. Donec dignissim elit sed ullamcorper semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas facilisis, risus eu varius lacinia, diam tortor volutpat ipsum,
            eu luctus neque massa quis leo. Phasellus blandit pellentesque justo non ornare. Cras et elit sit amet quam consequat viverra vel a diam. Pellentesque rutrum, dolor sit amet condimentum dapibus, lorem est dapibus orci, a congue ante ante ac
            lectus. Donec maximus pretium venenatis. Cras ex leo, pellentesque in libero sit amet, auctor congue sapien. Aliquam nec mi commodo ipsum sagittis tincidunt. Vestibulum sollicitudin laoreet eros vel finibus. Integer accumsan consectetur neque
            eget sodales.</p>
        </section>
        <!-- #post-## -->
        <!-- You can start editing here. -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#content-wrap -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Change the flex direction

By default `flex-direction` is set to `row` by setting this to `column` the content will be flexed top to bottom instead of left to right.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 990px;
}
#content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.image-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content-wrap" class="fluid clearfix" data-content="content">
    <!-- /#start content-wrap -->
    <div class="image-header">
      <img src="https://staging.orsgroup.com.au/eapportal/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/07/ORS-Internals-960x211-EmployServOccu21.jpg" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="content" class="sixteen columns">
        <section class="post-9 page type-page status-publish hentry">

          <h1>Home Page</h1>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis tortor vel diam volutpat luctus. Proin placerat nisl nulla, in mattis ex consectetur quis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae enim
            vel nibh hendrerit dignissim a et ante. Mauris eget tempus nunc. Donec dignissim elit sed ullamcorper semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas facilisis, risus eu varius lacinia, diam tortor volutpat ipsum,
            eu luctus neque massa quis leo. Phasellus blandit pellentesque justo non ornare. Cras et elit sit amet quam consequat viverra vel a diam. Pellentesque rutrum, dolor sit amet condimentum dapibus, lorem est dapibus orci, a congue ante ante ac
            lectus. Donec maximus pretium venenatis. Cras ex leo, pellentesque in libero sit amet, auctor congue sapien. Aliquam nec mi commodo ipsum sagittis tincidunt. Vestibulum sollicitudin laoreet eros vel finibus. Integer accumsan consectetur neque
            eget sodales.</p>
        </section>
        <!-- #post-## -->
        <!-- You can start editing here. -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#content-wrap -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks HH.

Comment: No problem @Steve, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should be good to go if you just do:

```
.image-header {

    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute; /* If it works without this, remove it. If it doesn't, you'll need to add a margin to not make the text go under it */
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

Comment: This will definitely make image 100% wide but the text below it will overlap on the image and will need to padding of at least 200px.

Comment: @TanyaSinha Ah, that's very true. Didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

```
#content-wrap {
  display:flex 
}
```

this part of code creates the issues because the flex property specifies the length of the item, relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container. Remove it from your code and then check it

You can use:

```
#content-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.image-header,.container {
  -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
}
```

this will solve your problem and you can use flex box model also

Comment: Thanks Tanya. I've built the template around using the flex model. Is there a work around that doesn't involve removing `display: flex;`?